# can't get apostrophe to escape returned text through a variable in my wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, escaping

I have built the following function to pick driver names out of a table and return them pre-fixed with an image & inside a hyperlink.

This works fine, except for one driver's surname has "van't" in it. An apostrophe!

My function won't work on this name with the apostrophe. I know normally it's possible to add a backslash if just typing in an echo or similar.

I have also tried surrounding the variables with wordpress' esc_attr__ , and a few similar 'google-stackoverflow' suggested tags.

For the life of me I can't get the string replace to carry out on this name though.

Does anybody have any other ideas how I should go about escaping the apostrophe when it is being called in from a variable?

This is my function - $profiletitle is the variable containing the stray 'apostrophe surname':

```
 function replace_stuff($texto) {

  if (is_front_page() || is_page('2611') || is_child('2611') || get_post_type() == 'drivers') {

    query_posts('post_type=drivers');
   if (\have_posts()) : 
   while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  $profiletitle = get_the_title();
  $profilenationality = get_custom_field('driver_nationality');
  $profilelink = get_the_permalink();


  $replace_magic[$profiletitle] =  '<a href="' . $profilelink . '">' . do_shortcode($profilenationality) . '<span class="no_translate">' .  $profiletitle . '</span></a>';

endwhile;
    endif;
}

$textp = str_replace(array_keys( (array)$replace_magic), $replace_magic, $texto);

return $textp . wp_reset_query();
}

add_filter('tablepress_table_output', 'replace_stuff');
```

Many thanks!

Comment: "My function won't work on this name with the apostrophe." What error message does it throw exactly?

Comment: I'm not getting an error - I have wordpress's debug on. It's just showing the_title() without the newly appended bits. all the other 'titles' I have from the other posts in the custom post type are displaying just fine.

Comment: I mean that I see the name 'van't' without the image & hyperlink all the others get.